# Unity3D WWW responseHeaders Duplicate Date

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, http-headers, postman

I am having a strange behaviour that I cannot figure out why. I use the code below to get the internet time.

```
WWW www = new WWW("http://google.com");
yield return www;

if (www.error == null) {
    if (www.responseHeaders.ContainsKey("Date")) {
        string dateString = www.responseHeaders["Date"];
        Debug.Log("Eray - response date: " + dateString); // TODO: remove

        ............

    } else {
        Debug.LogError("InternetTime: " + "Key 'Date' not found");
        callback(null);
    }
} else {
    Debug.LogError("InternetTime: " + www.error);
    callback(null);
}
```

The problem is that **Google's response header** returns a duplicate value of the header 'Date' as below whereas **Postman** returns properly.

**Unity WWW:**

```
Eray - response date: Wed, 06 Dec 2017 14:29:56 GMT,Wed, 06 Dec 2017 14:29:56 GMT
```

**Postman:**

```
Date →Wed, 06 Dec 2017 14:37:05 GMT
```

Comment: Add user agent to the request. maybe Google is checking that.

Comment: I have tried this : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36" but still same. I have fetched the agent from my chrome by using the code :  "javascript:alert(navigator.userAgent)" on my Chrome's console